# Multiple <option> required on <select>

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

Select tag `presents` has got a long list of options. How can I make sure that at least 2 options are selected by the user? The first option is required, I also need the second to be required.

Here's the code:

```
    <select name="presents[]" id="presents" class="vv-select2-multiple" multiple required>
        <?php foreach(get_from_group('person', 'any', -1, ['tipo' => 'member']) as $member):?>
            <option value="<?= $member->ID ?>" <?php selected(get_user_person()->ID, $member->ID)?> required><?= $member->post_title; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Save your chosen options to an array and then check the array.length if its over 2 run your required code.

Comment: @dalelandry No.  It's not really a JS issue.  And the `presents[]` is already an array.  Maybe you could use JS to disable the submit button until there are two options selected.

Comment: Why not check that before submitting the form in JS, or after submitting in PHP code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Also, how is this related to Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Your select tag `presents` is an array already. Check the array length to make sure you have at least 2 options selected. When the form is submitted, try this on your `php` page:

```
$presents = $_POST['presents'];
if (count($presents) >= 2) {
    // Here you are sure that you have at least two options selected.
    // Do whatever you wish here. 
}
```

Or else, you can also get the same result with jquery.

```
function checkCount() {
    if($('#presents option').is(':selected')) {
        count = $('#presents option:selected').length;
        console.log(count);
        if (count >= 2) {
            console.log('Selected option are greater than or equal to 2');
        } else {
            console.log('Selected options are less than two');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('No options are selected!!!')
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    checkCount();
    $('#presents').on('change', checkCount);
})
```

[Try this online](https://playcode.io/970203).

Comment: You need to catch when there is no selection or it will generate "`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`"

Comment: Dear @Misunderstood, thanks for the point; I just edited the answer to take care of that.

Comment: Won't onchange fire each time an option is selected?   I don't use jQuery.  In JS onchange will fire on each selection.

Comment: What you should do is disable the submit button until there are at least two options selected.